# ROR: capybara spec for test pagination by setting 1 entry par page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Want capybara rspec for testing the pagination in the view

kaminari pagination  is used.

```
            <table>
              <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="no">Buil No</th>
                <th class="buil_name">Buil Name</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <% @buildings.each_with_index do |buil, index| %>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="no"><%= buil.no %></td>
                    <td class="buil_name"><%= buil.name %></td>
                  </tr>
              <% end %>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>

        <%= paginate @buildings %>
```

As here pagination is displaying 50 rows paer page,
But in my test database there is only 4 rows in table , and I want to test for pagination
so I have to test 1 or 2 entry per page.

So how i set 1 building pere page for pagination?

Comment: It would help if you gave some details of what you have tried, and where it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have `paginates_per 50` in your model:

```
# spec_helper.rb
Kaminari.configure do |config|
  config.default_per_page = 1
end
```

Otherwise:

```
# spec_helper.rb
Building.paginates_per 1
```

Comment: Thank you #Dimitri , I have implemented your solution and it's work fine.